# Is the Mapbox MBXCLLiveTrackingClient timeoutAllowedCheck stream in the Xcode debugger a side effect?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have an iOS app using the Mapbox iOS SDK 10.11.0-rc.1 that prints the following line every five seconds completely flooding the debugger console:

```
2023-02-28 17:04:11.470592-0800 xxx[5422:353138] -[MBXCLLiveTrackingClient timeoutAllowedCheck]
2023-02-28 17:04:16.476104-0800 xxx[5422:353138] -[MBXCLLiveTrackingClient timeoutAllowedCheck]
2023-02-28 17:04:21.481685-0800 xxx[5422:353138] -[MBXCLLiveTrackingClient timeoutAllowedCheck]
2023-02-28 17:04:26.486241-0800 xxx[5422:353138] -[MBXCLLiveTrackingClient timeoutAllowedCheck]
```

I found no documentation on this.

- Is this a side effect or intended behavior?
- What is its purpose?
- Can it be disabled?

**Xcode 14.2**
**Mapbox iOS SDK 10.11.0-rc.1**

Answer (score 0):

The log message `-[MBXCLLiveTrackingClient timeoutAllowedCheck]` that you are seeing is simply a debugging message that was left in the code for diagnostic purposes. It does not indicate an error or any issue with your app. This message was removed in version v10.12 of the Mapbox iOS SDK.

In short, you can ignore this log message as it has no impact on your app's functionality. If you update to the latest version of the Mapbox iOS SDK, you should no longer see this message in your console output.